# Widget without DIV wrapper

Tags: widgets, widget-text

Whenever I add a text widget it adds a `div` around the content I add. E.g.

```
<div class="textwidget">
   <my content>
</div>
```

which messes up the formatting of some of my content.

Is there a way to NOT have the surrounding div?
i.e. a widget that **just** outputs  without any surrounding divs?

Comment: You could create your own widget that does this but the result would probably cause more issues than the ones you're trying to solve. Perhaps you should look to CSS for a solution

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [`register_sidebar()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar) function in the codex:

- `before_widget` & `after_widget` - are your wrapper.
- `before_title` & `after_title` - are your wrapper around the widget title.

They are optional parameters that can be omitted but as @Tom J Nowell noted, you'll encounter many headaches without proper sidebar structure.